# Unicode error python

Tags: python, unicode

Here is gist of the problem.
I am trying get data from a REST API call and storing them in a database.
Then I running few queries to find out TOP 3 users. I could not pack all the list values that I am getting from MySQL to a JSON file.

I am unable to get past the following issue.

> File "/Users/id1/Downloads/user1.py", line 58, in
>   get_last_three_installed_user
>       results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
>
> TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

This is the output of a SQL query

```
+----------------+--------+-------------+------------+-----------------+
| name           | gender | nationality | registered | registered_date |
+----------------+--------+-------------+------------+-----------------+
| mélissa robin  | female | FR          | 1437761753 | 2015-07-24      |
| agathe fabre   | female | FR          | 1437002837 | 2015-07-15      |
| soline morin   | female | FR          | 1436138376 | 2015-07-05      |
+----------------+--------+-------------+------------+-----------------+
```

If I try str(name) I am getting following error:

> name = str(json_dict["results"][result]["user"]["name"]["first"]) +"
>   "+ str(json_dict["results"][result]["user"]["name"]["last"])
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in
>   position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is my code:

```
def get_last_three_installed_user(file_type):
    count_sql = "select name,gender,nationality,registered,DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(registered), '%Y-%m-%d') registered_date from install_user order by from_unixtime(registered) desc limit 3 "
    curs.execute(count_sql)
    columns = [column[0] for column in curs.description]
    results = []

    if file_type == 'csv':
        fp = open('user_list.csv', 'w')
        csvFile = csv.writer(fp)
        rows = curs.fetchall()
        csvFile.writerows(rows)
    else:
        with open('file_count.json', 'w') as outfile:
            for row in curs.fetchall():
               results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
               print results
            output = {"TableData": results}
            json.dump(output, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: please post  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The first error message doesn't make sense to me, since I don't see any attempted "calls". The second one does, though - you won't be able to `str()` something containing non-ascii characters. What made you try adding the `str` call?

Comment: m.wasowski - Hope this code is fine with you.

Comment: You appear to have assigned something to `zip` or `dict` other than the built-in object. Calling `str()` on a unicode object with contents outside the ASCII range will always fail; use explicit encoding instead.

Comment: Never mind I figured out.

Answer (score 0):

This code pretty much took care of it.

```
def get_last_three_installed_user(file_type):
    count_sql = "select name,gender,nationality,registered,DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(registered), '%Y-%m-%d') registered_date from install_user order by from_unixtime(registered) desc limit 1,3 "
    curs.execute(count_sql)
    results = []
    dict1 ={}

    if file_type == 'csv':
        fp = open('user_list.csv', 'w')
        csvFile = csv.writer(fp)
        rows = curs.fetchall()
        csvFile.writerows(rows)
    else:
        with open('file_count.json', 'w') as outfile:
            for row in curs.fetchall():
                for idx, col in enumerate(curs.description):
                    dict1[col[0]] = row[idx]
                results.append(dict1)
            output = {"TableData": results}
            json.dump(output, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii=False)
```